# How I can send in ajax request file with other string's variables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, html, file-upload

I am trying to create ajax call and send data with file and other variables, I also using django if it help.

My try:

**js file:**

```
$("#save-new-request-testBtn").click(function(){
var project = $('#project').val();
var newRequestStreams = $('#newRequestStreams').val();
var request_bot_file = $('#request_bot_file')[0].files;

submit_new_request(project,newRequestStreams,request_bot_file );
```

});

```
 function submit_new_request(project,newRequestStreams,request_bot_file ){
url= "add/submit";
console.log(project);
var new_data;

csfr();
$.ajax({
     async:false,
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
     data: ({project:project,newRequestStreams:newRequestStreams,request_bot_file :request_bot_file }),
     success: function(data){
         new_data= data;

         console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#formError").html(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);

                 }
});
console.log('fgcfg');

return new_data;

}
```

issue is with the select of the file:
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('file') does not support selection.

any good advice how to make it work?

thanks,
Cfir

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: is it the right way? because it not working?

Comment: Which part isn't working exactly?

Comment: to find problem exactly.

Comment: issue is with the select of the file:Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('file') does not support selection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download JSON.js or JSON2.js here https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.
And do the following:

```
var myDataToSend = JSON.stringify(
    {
        project: project,
        newRequestStreams : newRequestStreams,
        request_bot_file : request_bot_file
    }
);
```

And the ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : "POST",
    enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
    data : 'data=' + myDataToSend ,
    success : function(){},
    error : function(){},
})
```

What language is the backend, for example in PHP you could do:

```
$jsonArr = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Get the equivalent for json_decode in your language.
Python would be:

```
# Python 2.6+
import json
result = json.loads(post_variable_data_from_ajax)
```

Comment: THE OP tags Django, so backend appears to be python.

Comment: issue is with the select of the file:Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('file') does not support selection.

Comment: Try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects